# Merging sub parts of multiple files into a single file in Java

Tags: java

I have n files each containing m blocks of data.

```
    File 0 Contents:
    file0.block1
    file0.block2
    file0.block3
    file0.block4
    ..
    file0.blockM
```

```
    File 1 Contents:
    file1.block1
    file1.block2
    file1.block3
    file1.block4
    ..
    file1.blockM
```

...

```
    File n Contents:
    fileN.block1
    fileN.block2
    fileN.block3
    fileN.block4
    ..
    fileN.blockM
```

The blocks are of variable size. Blocks having the same Id can have variable sizes across different files.

The merged file should look like this.

```
    Merged File Contents:
    file0.block1
    file1.block1
    ...
    fileN.block1
    
    file0.block2
    file1.block2
    ...
    fileN.block2
    
    ..
    
    file0.blockM
    file1.blockM
    ...
    fileN.blockM
```

Comment: If I open an input stream for each file, I can run out of memory if n is too big. 
If I open and close input streams, I will need to repeat this m x n times. 
Can there be a middle ground?

Comment: How many files are there on average, at most, at least? Depending on what the order of `N` is, keeping each input stream open might not be a problem. Also, input streams don't actually require *that much* memory. They mostly consume file handles, but that's a resource that is somewhat rarer to run out of than memory (still quite possible, though).

Comment: is each block a separate line?

Comment: @CodeMan Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have tried so far and write the problems you have with that code.

Comment: @CodeMan, are you sure memory is the problem? Presumably you would write each block you have read straight to the output file?

Comment: Are these files text files? In other words, can I open one of the files in a text editor and read its contents? Or are the files data files, for example a file that contains a GIF image? What, exactly, is a _block_ of data in one of these files?

Comment: These are not text files. They are some application specific binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Is N really so large that keeping the files open is not an option? At least on Linux the hard limit of possible open files is quite large. `ulimit -Hn` gives me 1048576 on Xubuntu 20.04. The soft limit is much smaller with 1024 by default but that can be raised using `ulimit -n N`. Not sure what sensible values for N are but you can try using what you think is the maximum N you will encounter in your application. Note: I do not know if Java imposes limits beyond what the OS does or if keeping a million files open costs a lot of memory (I would expect the memory cost for an InputStream to be in the order of a few KBs). Also, no idea how this works on Windows.

The only middle ground I can think of between either opening/closing files all the time or keeping all files open all the time would be to process a number of files at a time and join them into temporary files, then join the temp files to form the final result. Clearly, that avoids the opening/closing scenario but comes at the cost of re-writing the data more often, which might be slow on spinning disks and wears down SSDs if the files are of any significant size.